# How to get JSON response data count

Tags: javascript, json, angular

How to get JSON response data count for response. I'm getting JSON response like `1234`.Here need to get the JSON data count. I tried with `length, size, Object.keys(res).length` as well.
Please suggest me,

```
 entities: any = [];

   this.http.get("/testAPI/testAPI123").subscribe((res) => {
        this.entities = res as any; //giving json data like 1234
   });
```

Comment: How exactly does `1234` conform to JSON standard? Please provide a sample of the output from the API.

Comment: @MichaelD `1234` is valid JSON https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Could you please elaborate? Does it mean `var i = 1234` be considered a valid JSON?

Comment: @MichaelD I'm not sure that is what the OP is saying. There is no `var i = 1234` in the code?

Comment: @MichaelD any number is considered valid JSON. So yeah `const i = 1234` would be valid JSON, though I would agree it feels like a code smell for sure... would be better to just do `{"myNumber": "1234"}` IMO

Comment: Please @Rajasekhar may you add an example of what is returned from the API?

Comment: @maxshuty that's a JavaScript number, not JSON. JSON is a string that needs to be parsed before use in JS.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for the info. Yet I wait for more info from OP for their question _"JSON data count"_.

Comment: @evolutionxbox https://jsonlint.com/ `1234`  = valid JSON. I wasn't saying that entire variable was valid JSON (ie `"const i = 1234"` obviously would be invalid), my bad if it came off that way. I was implying that if you set a JSON body to the value of `i` that yes, it would be valid.

Comment: @maxshuty no problem, thank you for clarifying